# Slack blocks + sending response doesn't work in python, not even when async - only in CURL

Tags: python, django, slack-api

- Sending block to Slack - it shows on slack correctly.
- Button is clicked, I am getting the interactive event webhook.
- webhook returns 200 OK to slack, not before scheduling an async POST to the `response_url`
- the return message is posted to `response_url` AFTER the 200 ack is returned from the webhook function
- Slack responds 404 to the `response_url`
- that same response URL works when curled outside of python....

I don't get why slack rejects the posted return message with 404 when the very same response_url works when used in curl outside of python.

my webhook processor:

```
def slack_webhook(request):
    json_dict = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    token = json_dict['token'] if 'token' in json_dict else None
    message = json_dict['message'] if 'message' in json_dict else None
    trigger_id = json_dict['trigger_id'] if 'trigger_id' in json_dict else None
    response_url = json_dict['response_url'] if 'response_url' in json_dict else None
    actions = json_dict['actions'] if 'actions' in json_dict else None

    for action in actions:
        print(f"** received action {action['action_id']}")
        print(f"** response_url: {response_url}")
        print(f"** trigger_id: {trigger_id}")

        payload = {
            "replace_original": True,
            "text": "Success!",
        }

        # async via Celery...
        send_slack_interactive_response.delay(response_url, payload, trigger_id)
        
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

the async celery task which sends the

```
@app.task(bind=True, retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 10, 'countdown': 5})
def send_slack_interactive_response(self, response_url, payload, trigger_id):

    print(f"**  -> response_url: {response_url}")
    print(f"** -> trigger_id: {trigger_id}")

    if response_url and payload and trigger_id:
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        payload['trigger_id'] = trigger_id
        print(json.dumps(payload))
        r = requests.post(response_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
        print(r.__dict__)
```

This function fails with 404. however, when i take the `response_url`, `trigger_id` and create the exact same POST with command line `curl` - it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a comment on your code : You can do `token = json_dict.get("token", None)` that save you lot of code

On your problem :

1. Be sure Celery parameters is not weird encoded (response_url is send to messagerie and is encoded)
2. Be sure request parameters are well used (like using `json` instead of `data`...)

Comment: Silly me -- it WAS the json, vs. data on the request. Duh. Thanks.